# Google docs OCR implementation iphone

Tags: iphone, ocr, google-docs

I am trying to integrate google docs OCR feature in my iPhone app. Below is what google docs documentation says.

To perform OCR on a .pdf, .jpg, .png, or .gif file, include the ocr=true parameter when uploading a file:

```
POST /feeds/default/private/full?ocr=true
GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: <your authorization header here>
Content-Length: 1984
Content-Type: image/png
Slug: OCRd Doc

... png contents here ...
```

Now, I am using the following code to make that HTTP post request.

```
    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?ocr=true"];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Submit-top.png"];

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    int a = [data length];
    NSString *imgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d" ,a];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"3.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version:"];
    [request addValue:auth.accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization:"];
    [request addValue:imgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length:"];
    [request addValue:@"image/png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type:"];
    [request addValue:@"OCRd Doc" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Slug:"];




    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

but I get a response with status code 400.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using:

```
[request addValue:@"3.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version:"];
```

Use:

```
[request setValue:@"3.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];
```

Note the change from `addValue:` to `setValue:` and the removal of the colon in the `forHTTPHeaderField:` string.

Do the same for the rest of your `addValue:` lines.

`addValue:` appends whereas `setValue:` replaces.

Comment: Now it says unauthorized header. What do i need to put in the authorization field in the line below? [request addValue:auth.accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization:"];

Comment: Google recommends using OAuth 2.0, see here for details: http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Auth

Comment: After reading the documentation, i was able to to get the Auth token from google using ClientLogin but when posting a document, it returns belows error.<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Token invalid</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Token invalid</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>